# How can I segment already augmented images into smaller ones?

Tags: python, keras, annotations, label, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to figure out a way to segment a large already annotated image which I have the .json for into smaller images with python for the deep learning model as the image is very high in resolution and I need it to be 256x256, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read image with `cv2` then you have `numpy.array` and you can use indexes

```
img[ row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end ]
```

to get subimage - ie. `img[0:256,0:256]`

And you can repeate it in `for`-loops like

```
all_small = []

for row in range(0, height, 256):
    for col in range(0, width, 256):
        small = img[ row:row+256, col:col+256 ]
        all_small.append(small)
```